# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in rserve java

Tags: java, glassfish, centos6, netbeans-8, rserve

I am running an Rscript from Java which is having two functions one will return a data frame and other will return the column name of the data frame returned by function 1.

The code is running fine for 400 MB data but when I am testing with more than 400 MB it is throwing exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have tried many solutions for this to increase the heap size.

The solutions I have tried are:-

1. I have edited the domain.xml file of glassfish.
2. I have tried to set fore fully Java option using "set _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms1025m -Xmx4gm" and export JAVA_OPT= -Xms1025m -Xmx4g.
3. Edited the netbeans.conf file as

   netbeans_default_options="-J-Xms1025m -J-Xmx4g -J-Xss32m -J-XX:PermSize=128m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=2g -J-Xverify:none -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
4. Crontab with Java option -Xms1025m -Xmx4gm
5. Changed the netbeansproject->properties->run->vmoption also.

But still getting the same error.

And when I tried to check the heap size using the below Java code. It is showing something different. I am not getting which is correct and which is wrong. The heap size is changed or not. How to know it and how to solve this?
I got this code from some website while searching for the error.
 The output I am getting is
run:

JVM freeMemory: 10

JVM totalMemory also equals to initial heap size of JVM : 10

JVM maxMemory also equals to maximum heap size of JVM: 168

Used Memory in JVM: 162

freeMemory in JVM: 6

totalMemory in JVM shows current size of Java heap : 15

maxMemory in JVM: 168

JVM Bit size: amd64

Heap Size = 163123200

```
   public class MemoryUtil
   {

    private static final int MegaBytes = 10241024;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

           long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/MegaBytes;
           long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/MegaBytes;
           long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/MegaBytes;

           System.out.println("JVM freeMemory: " + freeMemory);
           System.out.println("JVM totalMemory also equals to initial heap size of JVM : "
                                     + totalMemory);
           System.out.println("JVM maxMemory also equals to maximum heap size of JVM: "
                                     + maxMemory);

           ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();

           for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
                 objects.add(("" + 10 * 2710));
           }

           freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / MegaBytes;
           totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / MegaBytes;
           maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / MegaBytes;

           System.out.println("Used Memory in JVM: " + (maxMemory - freeMemory));
           System.out.println("freeMemory in JVM: " + freeMemory);
           System.out.println("totalMemory in JVM shows current size of java heap : "
                                     + totalMemory);
           System.out.println("maxMemory in JVM: " + maxMemory);
      System.out.println("JVM Bit size: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));

         long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

    //Print the jvm heap size.
    System.out.println("Heap Size = " + heapSize);


       }
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the maximum heap size for the applications running inside Glassfish you only have to edit the setting in your `domain.xml`.

Stop Glassfish, open the file (`/GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml` for those who don't know) with a text editor and search for `Xmx` (the first result), it should look like this:

```
    <jvm-options>blabla</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Xmx512m</jvm-options>
```

It may contain another value if you already touched this. Change the value to something like this:

```
    <jvm-options>blabla</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Xmx4096m</jvm-options>
```

Note that Glassfish itself requires some memory to run, I suggest you add additional 350 MB only for Glassfish on your setting, if your hardware specs allow that.

Alternativly you can use the Glassfish Admin UI to change the setting:

[image: Xmx setting in Glassfish Admin UI]

Comment: Editing the domain.xml directly should probably not be the first way to do it. If you make a typo, you could make a bad situation worse! Also, be careful to edit the right profile, since `default-config` and `server-config` are in the same file.